# Classification of bimodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules, monoidal-categories, bimodules

In a monoidal category $(\mathcal C, \otimes)$ one can consider algebras (internal monoids) and bimodules over those algebras.

For which algebras $A, B$ can we classify all $(A, B)$-bimodules? What about $(A, A)$-bimodules? For which categories $\mathcal C$ can we classify these for all algebras in $\mathcal C$?

Comment: What do you mean "classify" ? if $A$ is "solid" (for $C$ nice enough, this is equivalent to asking that $1\to A$ be an epimorphism of rings) then there is a "classification" in terms of $B$-modules; but without a more precise meaning of the word it's going to be hard to answer sensibly

Comment: In any symmetric monoidal category, $(A,B)$-bimodules are the same as left $A \otimes B^{\mathrm{op}}$-modules or right $A^{\mathrm{op}} \otimes B$-modules.

Comment: This question is already meaningless for the most simple examples of monoidal categories.